# Why is string to date and back to string resulting in two different strings?

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat, datetime-format

My input string is:

```
"2016-06-13T14:20:09.866Z"
```

My output string is:

```
"2016-06-13T10:20:09.866-04"
```

Why are they different and how can I make it output in the same format as the input?

I convert from string to date:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", Locale.ENGLISH);
dateFormat.parse((String) date));
```

In a unit test, I convert the parsed date back into a string:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", Locale.ENGLISH);
dateFormat.format(date);
```

Comment: What is the last `z` in the date? Does that denote something?

Comment: Yes, @Codebender, according to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) ´Z` means offset 0 from UTC. It’s sometimes pronounced “Zulu” after that military “time zone”.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two dates are the same - only the format differs (one is 2pm UTC the other is 10am with an offset of -4 hours = 2pm UTC too).

So I suppose that what you want is to have the second string in UTC time zone too. In that case you can simply set the timezone of the second DateFormat:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", Locale.ENGLISH);
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why are they different and how can I make it output in the same format
> as the input?

***Both of them not only represent the same moment but are also in the same format, [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).***

`2016-06-13T14:20:09.866Z` represents a date-time in UTC. The `Z` in it is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

`2016-06-13T10:20:09.866-04` or `2016-06-13T10:20:09.866-04:00` represents a date-time at a timezone offset of `-04:00` hours i.e. this moment can be represented as `2016-06-13T14:20:09.866+00:00` or `2016-06-13T14:20:09.866Z` in UTC.

Note that the legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Demo using the modern API:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odtWithMinusFourHoursOffset = OffsetDateTime.parse("2016-06-13T10:20:09.866-04");
        System.out.println(odtWithMinusFourHoursOffset);

        OffsetDateTime odtWithSameMomentInUtc = odtWithMinusFourHoursOffset.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(odtWithSameMomentInUtc);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2016-06-13T10:20:09.866-04:00
2016-06-13T14:20:09.866Z
```

#### Did you notice, we did not use `DateTimeFormatter` here?

The modern date-time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the date-time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>