# I am trying to get the DateTimeFormatter for a date string in joda time

Tags: android, jodatime, datetime-format

I need the format string for a date that is formatted like this: `2017-06-14T00:00:00Z`.

Currently, I have:

```
DateTimeFormatter DT_SCHEDULE_FORMATTER_START_TIME = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
```

If I parse a the string `2017-06-14T00:00:00Z` with this, it gives me the right time in UTC.

But when I take a `DateTime` object and try to do:

```
String strNow = new DateTime().toString(DT_SCHEDULE_FORMATTER_START_TIME);
```

I get something like `2017-06-14T00:00:00 -07:00`

I've looked in the documentation and can't seem to find the right formatting string.

Comment: **For future visitors of this page:** Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67478337/10819573) for a solution using the modern date-time API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the [`DateTime()` constructor uses your system's default timezone](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime--), and the `Z` pattern in the formatter [prints the timezone offset](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

Your system's default timezone offset is `-07:00`, that's why you get this output.

If you want exactly the output with `Z` in the end, you must convert the `DateTime` object to an `org.joda.time.Instant`:

```
String strNow = new DateTime("2017-06-14T00:00:00Z").toInstant().toString();
```

`strNow` will be `2017-06-14T00:00:00.000Z`.

If you want to get the current time in UTC (instead of parsing a `String`), you must tell explicity to `DateTime` constructor to use UTC, using `new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC)`.

---

The code above also prints the milliseconds. If you don't want this, another alternative is to use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    // append Z if offset is zero (UTC)
    .appendTimeZoneOffset("Z", true, 2, 2)
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();
String strNow = new DateTime("2017-06-14T00:00:00Z").toInstant().toString(formatter);
```

This will format the date accordinlgy (without the milliseconds):

> 2017-06-14T00:00:00Z

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the parseDateTime function

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
DateTime dateTime = f.parseDateTime("2017-06-14T00:00:00Z");
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

"Z" in format is RFC 822 time zone

> For formatting, if the offset value from GMT is 0, "Z" is produced. If
>   the number of pattern letters is 1, any fraction of an hour is
>   ignored.
>
> For parsing, "Z" is parsed as the UTC time zone designator. General
>   time zones are not accepted.

If you want to get string for UTC - you should force timezone:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
String strNow = dateTime.toString(DT_SCHEDULE_FORMATTER_START_TIME);
```